# Suppose a spinning sphere in a frictionless environment, will it deviate from its location?

Tags: angular-momentum

I was reading in a patent that a rotating spherical body in space will experience a curvilinear translation, due to the conservation of angular momentum. This confuses me, as per my understanding if there is no friction, or any other force applied, conservation of angular momentum will keep the same rotating speed but I do not see why it will make it move/translate from its location. On the other hand, I have seen a video of a spinning object in the ISS changing direction alternatively, and I also do not know how it happens, in that case there is no translation that can be observed, but there is still friction with the air. Anyone can give some insights? Thanks!

Comment: Regarding the spinning object in the ISS: For asymmetrical objects, angular momentum is not parallel to angular velocity. Angular velocity can change while angular momentum stays constant. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_racket_theorem).